# dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_getres

Tags: database, mongodb

> dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_getres Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/mongo I am getting this error on my Mac osx 10.11.6 el
>   capitan: dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_getres Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/mongo (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12) Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib in /usr/local/bin/mongo.

I am trying to get the `MongoDB` shell up and running on my MAC so I can run queries.

I have downloading the mongo db enterprise app and added it to my $PATH using my .bash_profile and save file.

when I run any mongo CMD I get dyld: `Symbol not found: _clock_getres`

I expect after running the code to get some interaction from Mongo DB but instead I get the error msg